# How to receive onbackpressed within DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, dialogfragment

**How can I receive the OnBackPressed event within a DialogFragment?**

I'm creating a custom `DialogFragment` causing it to call `onCreateView()` and not `onCreateDialog`.

Therefore I'm unable to set an `OnDismissListener` or `OnCancelListener` since mDialog is null.

I'm calling my DialogFragment like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).
                                getSupportFragmentManager();    
DialogFragmentCustom newFragment = DialogFragmentCustom.newInstance(...);
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
```

Do you have an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: can you post the code of activity that you use to show the dialog

Comment: what do you exactly mean? I'm using the code which I already posted in my question.

Comment: how do you show the dialog is pressing a button? I want the code you use to show the dialog.

Comment: This is actually the code to show the DialogFragment. After the execution of this code - the overriden onCreateView Methode ist called. And showing correctly my DialogFragment.

Comment: The other possibilty would be to call: 
`DialogFragmentCustom newFragment DialogFragmentCustom.newInstance(mIndexPropertiesManager,
                                        mFavoriteManager, favorite);
                        newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Dialog");
                        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();` But then you can not provide a custom layout.